# Django JSONB find value less than

Tags: django, jsonb

I have a sample JSONB dataset below, this is one column entry from a single row:

```
[
  {
    "id": "xxx",
    "type": "thing",
    "value": {
      "date": "2023-10-21"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "xxy",
    "type": "thing",
    "value": {
      "date": "2023-10-19"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to find if one of the 'date' values is less than 'some_value' - please see pseudocode below:

```
Q(columnName__{arrayOfItems}__value__date__lt=some_value)
```

I can find if an exact value exists but need the value to be variable, for example the below works:

```
Q(columnName__contains=[{"value": {"date": "2023-10-21"}}])
```

I think I need to add a subquery for the date itself ("2023-10-21") to see if it is less than some other date but currently unable to do this. Spent a few days so far, any comments welcome to help guide me.

Many thanks in advance.